NET MAUI unable to implement social login for Android and iOS
I'm developing a MAUI app for Android and iOS. It is a porting of a old Xamarin Forms App.
I need to implement Google Sign In and Apple Sign In.
In the old app was used the Plugin.GoogleClient and a custom renderer for the Apple sign in on iOS only.
On MAUI the plugin is not compatible anymore.
I tried using WebAuthenticator but I got "Custom URI scheme is not enabled for your Android client." when trying it.
I can't modify the ID client OAuth 2.0 on Google because it is used by the old app in production.
I also tried with Firebase but no luck, compilation error, no documentation found for maui.
I don't know what to do now, I wasted a lot of time.
Which is the best practice in 2024 for social login in maui app using .net 8?

You can use the Maui version of the GoogleClient.
https://github.com/beglaryan-alen/Plugin.GoogleClient.MAUI

Thank you so much. Do you know a plugin for Apple Sign in too?
